# Can we rein-in unnecessary edits?

Tags: discussion

I do not make very many questions or answers, but I notice that almost all of them are edited by the same user.  Sometimes these edits are trivially useful, but often they are completely unnecessary.  Most recently, I had capitalization changed by an answerer so that it did NOT match the quoted capitalization in his/her own answer!

Can we limit these completely unnecessary edits?

Comment: Got any examples? Also you only get a maximum of 1000 rep from suggested edits and once you no longer have to suggest edits (2k rep) you don’t get any rep from edits anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I didn't know that. I guess it's not for the actual rep, but there are other benefits to unnecessary edits, (such as badges).

Comment: If it’s the user mentioned in the answer by Valorum they already have all editing badges I believe.

Comment: Yeah, there's a hell of a lot of unnecessary editing going on on this site, but they're mostly by users with >2k rep who don't get the +2 for editing.

Comment: Okay, so it has been pointed out that there would be no site benefit to the unnecessary edit, and also that the edit may not have been as unnecessary as I thought, so then this is just a duplication of Unnecessary editing- Why would people do it?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - I can't speak for Edlothiad, but the reason I often edit people's question is to correct simple errors of grammar and spelling like the one that you made. Since your question is now improved, perhaps we'd be better asking *"Can we please make more necessary edits?"*

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot well tag excerpts and wiki edits go on until 20K.

Comment: @Stormblessed correct but that wasn’t really relevant to the discussion here so I left them out.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/220565/revisions) is the question you're referring to, Edlothiad's edit was perfectly acceptable, correcting an error in the grammar of your post (where you had failed to properly capitalise some letters).

It's also worth noting that Edlo is already at 2000 rep and already has [all of the relevant badges for editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/68872/edlothiad?tab=badges), which means that they [didn't receive any (personal) benefit for correcting your mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep), they merely did it out of the kindness of their heart.

Comment: The capitalization change was not to fix a mistake, though, the original was consistent with the quote in his own answer

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - Tolkien uses the capitalised version pretty consistently. In this case, the quote is from someone talking about the circles in a non-literal sense but you're talking about the actual Circles of the World, so a capital would apply.

Comment: *trivially edits answer about trivial edits*

Comment: @Stormblessed - One of the simple joys of having over 2k rep is the ability to trivially edit things.

Comment: @Valorum ...The ability to make trivial edits doesn't make it appropriate or acceptable.  I don't think trivially editing things in general is a good idea.  Small improvements, sure; but _trivial_ edits?  I thought that was discouraged network wide.

Comment: @JMac Relax, Valorum is obviously joking...

Comment: If only he was ever *not* "obviously joking".

Comment: @TARS - When it comes to good grammar, I'm ***deadly serious.***